# How nested HERE DOC works in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to format nested HERE document in bash script but I ended up getting errors. This works since I do not format anything. But for a better readability I am trying to format the below function.

```
function test_func {
    : '
    my test func
    '

ssh -i /path/to/identity_file $TEST@${IP} << EOF
cd ~/
mkdir -p some_dir
some commands
if [ -f some_quries.sql ]
then 
ssh -i /path/to/identity_file $TEST@${IP} << EOSQL 
some_queries.sql; some_other_queries.sql;
exit;
EOSQL
fi
exit
EOF
```

When I try to format(I tried couple of the options but no luck):

```
function test_func {
    : '
    my test func
    '

    ssh -i /path/to/identity_file $TEST@${IP} << \EOF
    cd ~/
    some commands
    if [ -f some_quries.sql ]
    then 
        ssh -i /path/to/identity_file $TEST@${IP} << \EOSQL 
        some_queries.sql; some_other_queries.sql;
        exit;
    EOSQL
    fi
exit
EOF
```

I have tried with also <<-EOF and <<-EOSQL but I end up getting here-document at line N delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'EOSQL'). Can someone guide me on this?

I guess I also tried this:

```
EOSQL
fi
exit
EOF
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: It is important to care of special vairables like \$, they musst sometimes escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `<<-` form, and the indentation **must** be done with tab characters (not spaces). From `man bash`:

> ```
>    If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are
>    stripped  from  input  lines  and  the line containing delimiter.  This
>    allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a  natural
>    fashion.
> ```

Ex. given

```
$ cat heredoc.sh 
#!/bin/bash

    cat <<EOF1
    Hello from level 1
        cat <<EOF2
        Hello from level 2
        EOF2
    EOF1
```

then

```
$ ./heredoc.sh 
./heredoc.sh: line 8: warning: here-document at line 3 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF1')
    Hello from level 1
        cat <<EOF2
        Hello from level 2
        EOF2
    EOF1
```

whereas

```
$ cat heredoc.sh 
#!/bin/bash

    cat <<-EOF1
    Hello from level 1
        cat <<-EOF2
        Hello from level 2
        EOF2
    EOF1
```

then

```
$ ./heredoc.sh 
Hello from level 1
cat <<-EOF2
Hello from level 2
EOF2
```

Comment: I have not able to verify in the actual scripts. Once I get back I will update here but seems good to me. If that works I will upvote and accept this as answer.

Comment: This indeed worked for me